# prevent launchctl from starting a anonymous process

Tags: launchd

I have installed dnsmasq and now I want to be able to start it with launchctl. The problem is that every time I start the app launchctl starts an anonyous process instead of using the specified label.

```
10247   -   0x100107c30.anonymous.dnsmasq
-       0   com.example.dnsmasq
```

But I want it to be

```
10247    0  com.example.dnsmasq
```

The problem with the anonymous process is that I can't stop it with launchctl. When I run

```
launchctl stop com.example.dnsmasq
```

the anonymous process still stays alive.

Here is my property file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.dnsmasq</string>    
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq</string>
        <string>-p</string>
        <string>2155</string>
        <string>-R</string>
        <string>-A</string>
        <string>/.dev/127.0.0.1</string>
        <string>-x</string>
        <string>/usr/local/var/run/dnsmasq.pid</string>
    </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <false/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This very question has been asked on Stack Overflow: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924519/mac-os-x-prevent-launchctl-from-starting-a-anonymous-process). Please [avoid cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073).

Comment: sorry, was just about to delete it on SO. thaught this site would be a better place for this kind of quenstions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't actually `launchctl` creating a new process; it's most likely `dnsmasq`  itself.  If it `fork()`s into the background, `launchd` can't tell; then when it talks to `launchd`, `launchd` creates an anonymous entry for it.  Make sure `dnsmasq` doesn't background itself.

(The `-` listed for the regular `launchctl list` output indicates that the original `dnsmasq` process exited.)

Comment: Specifically, adding "-k" (or "--keep-in-foreground") to the ProgramArguments array should do it.  After doing this, you might also want to switch KeepAlive to true (so launchd will restart it if it quits for some reason).